# Curl command run smoothly but turning it into php and running got me "500 internal serve error"

Tags: php, curl

New to `curl` and am trying to run it in php. But running in php faces me with `500 internal server error`. Tried many methods, so would humbly love some advice.

**Current curl cmd:**

```
curl -X POST https://www.dbs.com/sandbox/api/sg/v1/oauth/authorize --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "clientId:clientId3" -d '{ "client_id":"demo", "client_assertion":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJEQlMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTUwNTg0OTYsImV4cCI6MTU1NTE0NDg5Niwic3ViIjoiSnd0IFNpZ25lZCBUb2tlbiBmb3IgRGVtZSBBcHAgUGFydG5lciBUb2tlbiBmbG93IiwiUEFSVFlfVFlQRSI6MywiQ0xJRU5UX0lEIjoiY2xpZW50SWQzIiwiQ0xJRU5UX1RZUEUiOiJQYXJ0bmVyIiwiQUNDRVNTIjoiQ29tbXVuaXR5IiwiU0NPUEUiOiJSRUFEIiwiYXVkIjoiUGFydG5lcnMiLCJqdGkiOiJTdGFuZGVyZEpXVFRva2VuMSJ9.Pl0YwiAs1UGzIdZXWbnFUGmBDfcKAlkZEcgYd_1NDo2co_6xziut1i0DTwcmcaKDlp7IuOOK1EXYKCmw0qlIu7ciM0DYmdD7M36VbC1TzTx-rVrUJmerRjh_EYY-S4txeCGZtZB0ow6bkgqh6GOz-uwcY7DOg90Da2qVtIk7seQtWi_709UEaNr3XTTorEiIaEqdUN3mmODpLTyrhpzXhop_JIGN1XzNZOfw-vM6DMhL_AiGjDZcvhbo9zPBmbmpECPudfXmtYxK2_4zTVtPDNxH_UUtOVza2MDdIBJCTxY4LQm7dfH-y3grRx6-KyBdUcrchTdqVPS1xATYCGo3QA" }'
```

**Current php code (after converting):**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.dbs.com/sandbox/api/sg/v1/oauth/authorize');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{ \"client_id\":\"demo\", \"client_assertion\":\"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJEQlMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTUwNTg0OTYsImV4cCI6MTU1NTE0NDg5Niwic3ViIjoiSnd0IFNpZ25lZCBUb2tlbiBmb3IgRGVtZSBBcHAgUGFydG5lciBUb2tlbiBmbG93IiwiUEFSVFlfVFlQRSI6MywiQ0xJRU5UX0lEIjoiY2xpZW50SWQzIiwiQ0xJRU5UX1RZUEUiOiJQYXJ0bmVyIiwiQUNDRVNTIjoiQ29tbXVuaXR5IiwiU0NPUEUiOiJSRUFEIiwiYXVkIjoiUGFydG5lcnMiLCJqdGkiOiJTdGFuZGVyZEpXVFRva2VuMSJ9.Pl0YwiAs1UGzIdZXWbnFUGmBDfcKAlkZEcgYd_1NDo2co_6xziut1i0DTwcmcaKDlp7IuOOK1EXYKCmw0qlIu7ciM0DYmdD7M36VbC1TzTx-rVrUJmerRjh_EYY-S4txeCGZtZB0ow6bkgqh6GOz-uwcY7DOg90Da2qVtIk7seQtWi_709UEaNr3XTTorEiIaEqdUN3mmODpLTyrhpzXhop_JIGN1XzNZOfw-vM6DMhL_AiGjDZcvhbo9zPBmbmpECPudfXmtYxK2_4zTVtPDNxH_UUtOVza2MDdIBJCTxY4LQm7dfH-y3grRx6-KyBdUcrchTdqVPS1xATYCGo3QA\" }");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Clientid: clientId3';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: How do you run the php code? Are you sure the error comes from the `dbs.com` API and not from your machine? The php code works for me.

Comment: hi, it might be coming from my machine, but i just can't detect it. I have already installed curl and have it running, what results do you get? Did you manage to get an access key token? Im running it with postman inside localhost.

Comment: Create a php file with the code and simply run it in cli like `php test.php`. If you would print the `$result` you will get a JSON response.

Comment: echoing `$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` should get you 200 for success but it's returning 500 which means internal server.

Comment: yes @Nik, i did get a response, but it isn't the one im looking for, it returns me the info i have given, but i am looking to generate a token key, i ran it in cURL and it works but not php, strange.

Comment: See my answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the API you are requesting requires a `User-Agent` header.

Try to run your `curl` command with `--verbose` flag, to see the request headers the `curl` is sending. You will get something like this:

```
$ curl --verbose -X POST https://www.dbs.com/sandbox/api/sg/v1/oauth/authorize --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "clientId:clientId3" -d '{ "client_id":"demo", "client_assertion":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJEQlMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTUwNTg0OTYsImV4cCI6MTU1NTE0NDg5Niwic3ViIjoiSnd0IFNpZ25lZCBUb2tlbiBmb3IgRGVtZSBBcHAgUGFydG5lciBUb2tlbiBmbG93IiwiUEFSVFlfVFlQRSI6MywiQ0xJRU5UX0lEIjoiY2xpZW50SWQzIiwiQ0xJRU5UX1RZUEUiOiJQYXJ0bmVyIiwiQUNDRVNTIjoiQ29tbXVuaXR5IiwiU0NPUEUiOiJSRUFEIiwiYXVkIjoiUGFydG5lcnMiLCJqdGkiOiJTdGFuZGVyZEpXVFRva2VuMSJ9.Pl0YwiAs1UGzIdZXWbnFUGmBDfcKAlkZEcgYd_1NDo2co_6xziut1i0DTwcmcaKDlp7IuOOK1EXYKCmw0qlIu7ciM0DYmdD7M36VbC1TzTx-rVrUJmerRjh_EYY-S4txeCGZtZB0ow6bkgqh6GOz-uwcY7DOg90Da2qVtIk7seQtWi_709UEaNr3XTTorEiIaEqdUN3mmODpLTyrhpzXhop_JIGN1XzNZOfw-vM6DMhL_AiGjDZcvhbo9zPBmbmpECPudfXmtYxK2_4zTVtPDNxH_UUtOVza2MDdIBJCTxY4LQm7dfH-y3grRx6-KyBdUcrchTdqVPS1xATYCGo3QA" }'

> POST /sandbox/api/sg/v1/oauth/authorize HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.dbs.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
> ...
```

So, then add the `User-Agent` header in your php code (any value will work):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/7.45.0');
```

The response (`$result`) will look like:

```
{
    "access_token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiIDogImh0dHBzOi8vY2FwaS5kYnMuY29tIiwiaWF0IiA6IDE1NTUwNjQ0MTE2MDQsICJleHAiIDogMTU1NTA2ODAxMTYwNCwic3ViIiA6ICJaR1Z0Ync9PSIsInB0eXR5cGUiIDogMywiY2xuaWQiIDogImNsaWVudElkMyIsImNsbnR5cGUiIDogIjIiLCAiYWNjZXNzIiA6ICIxRkEiLCJzY29wZSIgOiAiUkVBRCIgLCJhdWQiIDogImh0dHBzOi8vY2FwaS5kYnMuY29tL2FjY2VzcyIgLCJqdGkiIDogIjU5NjQxOTE1ODUzNzAwMjY5OTMiIH0.gij_4TyE6IX8mziHwK2eZaTXPtDDAnZ3nKAcKJYQJxs",
    "refresh_token" : "G/aZD0gOEoTuWETLSw+vt4OWIs8HFX/50psx2ShSaig=",
    "party_id" : "ZGVtbw==",
    "expire_in" : "1555068011604"
}
```

HTTP response code: `200`

Comment: Yes, that works for me. Thank you so much Nik! I even dreamed of this last night, someone would have the answer in the morning, I thank you again :)

Comment: Hey Nik this might sound like a weird request but I found out I can't just access the token like that, i have to login first. Do you mind watching this video and maybe point me in the right direction i should read on? Don't seem to find the right answer.

Video url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0smv2VSxHE&t=996s
At about 15:12 is the part i just can't wrap it around.

Thank you.